# Get related result and order by number of matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a many to many table like

```
flyer        tagged     tags
-----------------------------------
id             tid       id
flyer_name     fid       tag_name
```

And i currently working at the table tagged , what i wanted to do is **select all related result and order it by the number of matches**.

Lets say i have record ...
Table tagged

```
tid  fid
---------
80    1
80    2
80    3
2     1
2     2
2     6
1     3
1     4
30    5
30    6
```

First i want to select all flyer which tid is 2 or 80 then group it by fid So it will return fid 1,2,3

And now from 1,2,3 . I wanted to go through all of them by using CASE on the field tid if 2 or 80 then +1 to the variable 'matches' , then sort all fid by number of matches , also return all tags that belong to the flyer

```
Desired result
fid    matches    tags 
1         2       80,2      #matched with tags 80,2
2         2       80,2      #matched with tags 80,2
3         1       80,1      #matched with tags 80
6         1       2,30      #matched with tags 2
```

Here is my current mysql code which is not working , i tried to make question as simple as i can , please let me know if you think i should provide more. Thanks !

```
SELECT fid , tid , MATCHES FROM leon_tagged 
WHERE tid IN (2,80) 
CASE tid
    WHEN '2' then 1
    WHEN '80' then 1
    ELSE 0 END AS MATCHES
GROUP BY fid
ORDER BY MATCHES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. I think there's no need for the `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT T.fid
    , COUNT(T.tid) AS matches
    FROM tagged T
    WHERE T.tid IN (2, 80)
    GROUP BY T.fid
    ORDER BY matches DESC, T.fid ASC;
```

Hey, here's a test in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b02db6/4)

Added `tags` field:

```
SELECT T.fid
    , COUNT(T.tid) AS matches
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT T.tid) AS tags
    FROM tagged T
    WHERE T.tid IN (2, 80)
    GROUP BY T.fid
    ORDER BY matches DESC, T.fid ASC;
```

But I'm afraid you will have different desired result:

```
fid    matches    tags 
1         2       80,2      #matched with tags 80,2
2         2       80,2      #matched with tags 80,2
3         1       80        #matched with tags 80
6         1       2         #matched with tags 2
```

The last two rows are different from what you want, since you have stated earlier that you only want `tags` with `tid IN (2, 80)`.

Comment: Is it posibble to use the CASE and form a string of tags.
means result fid with 2,3 as some other variable? i try to get everything done by one query

Comment: Hmm, it is possible. Give me a minute.

Comment: @LeonArmstrong, can you edit your question to provide what you really want with the string of tags? I want to see the desired output.

Comment: I'm sorry i should have put more effort to explain this , Updated my question , its actually all tags that belong to the specific flyer

Comment: Thanks dude , you already done too much for me , the belong tags i be using nested join to get it, The answer is so simple and easy to understand!

Comment: No problem mate, everyone are willing to help.